# Extending tables of specific MySQL schema (chosen at runtime) with JPA

Tags: mysql, jpa, jdbc, eclipselink

I have the following problem with accessing a MySQL database via JPA / EclipseLink:

My MySQL server has multiple schemas, each representing an instance of the same database structure (i.e. each schema has the same tables - the schemas are just for different customers).

In my Eclipse preferences I configure which schema to use at runtime and start my application. So far, this worked well.

Now I added some fields to one of my entities and want JPA to reflect this change by executing some "ALTER TABLE ADD ..." command on the respective table in the current database schema. This still worked well for the first schema, the new columns can be seen in the database and can be accessed.

However, after I changed to the second schema and restarted the application, the new columns are NOT created in the table of the second schema. I wondered why, and tracked the problem down to the function "extendTables" in org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.TableCreator. This function boils down to the following (already shortened):

```
/**
 * This creates/extends the tables on the database.
 */
public void extendTables(DatabaseSession session, SchemaManager schemaManager, boolean build) {

    for (TableDefinition table : getTableDefinitions()) {
            AbstractSession abstractSession = (AbstractSession) session;
            ...
            if (alreadyExists) {
                //Assume the table exists, so lookup the column info

                String tableName = table.getTable()==null? table.getName(): table.getTable().getName();
                List<DatabaseRecord> columnInfo = null;

                // The following line looks up the column infos of ALL schemas!
                columnInfo = abstractSession.getAccessor().getColumnInfo(null, null, tableName, null, abstractSession);
                
                // hash the existing columns by name
                Map<DatabaseField, DatabaseRecord> columns = new HashMap(columnInfo.size());
                DatabaseField columnNameLookupField = new DatabaseField("COLUMN_NAME");
                DatabaseField schemaLookupField = new DatabaseField("TABLE_SCHEM");
                boolean schemaMatchFound = false;
                // Determine the probably schema for the table, this is a heuristic, so should not cause issues if wrong.
                String qualifier = table.getQualifier();
                if ((qualifier == null) || (qualifier.length() == 0)) {
                    qualifier = session.getDatasourcePlatform().getTableQualifier();
                }
                boolean checkSchema = (qualifier != null) && (qualifier.length() > 0);
                for (DatabaseRecord record : columnInfo) {
                    String fieldName = (String)record.get(columnNameLookupField);
                    if (fieldName != null && fieldName.length() > 0) {
                        DatabaseField column = new DatabaseField(fieldName);
                        
                        String schema = (String)record.get(schemaLookupField);
                        // Check the schema as well.  Ignore columns for other schema if a schema match is found.
                        if (schemaMatchFound) {
                            if (qualifier.equalsIgnoreCase(schema)) {
                                columns.put(column,  record);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (checkSchema) {
                                if (qualifier.equalsIgnoreCase(schema)) {
                                    schemaMatchFound = true;
                                    // Remove unmatched columns from other schemas.
                                    columns.clear();
                                }
                            }
                            // If none of the schemas match what is expected, assume what is expected is wrong, and use all columns.
                            columns.put(column,  record);
                        }
                    }
                }

                //Go through each field we need to have in the table to see if it already exists
                for (FieldDefinition fieldDef : table.getFields()){
                    DatabaseField dbField = fieldDef.getDatabaseField();
                    if (columns.get(dbField)== null) {
                        //field does not exist so add it to the table
                        table.addFieldOnDatabase(abstractSession, fieldDef);
                    }
                }
            
        }
    }
}
```

As it seems, the function indeed looks up the columns in ALL schemas. Then, it tries to filter out those that belong to the wrong schemas, comparing the desired schema to the information from "TABLE_SCHEM".

This looks like just what I want - except that the MySQL "schema" is translated to a "catalog" by JDBC, i.e. the information is stored in "TABLE_CAT" while "TABLE_SCHEM" is null. And "TABLE_CAT" is nowhere evaluated.

Can somebody see what I am getting wrong here and what would be a proper solution? Thank you in advance!

Comment: As using the JPA providers functionality to create tables works well for small or demo projects I would recommend to use a fully-featured database migration tool like Liquibase or Flyway

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that JPA is not the appropriate database management tool for commercial software? - If there is no solution for my problem within JPA, then we will need to consider some other technology, right. Not it that would have been or will be my decision which one to use ... But I can discuss the matter with my boss.

Comment: No JPA is not a database management tool. It allows to create or update the schema but is very limited. Often you also have to migrate the data when you change the schema and this isn't supported at all. Liquibase and Flyway are the tools to go

Comment: EclipseLink's schema management was meant as a tool to help developers prototype and setup tests quickly, not for production systems. It uses JDBC to issues statements that are exactly the same as the scripts it generates - you are better off having it generate scripts and then modify them as needed (DBA input) and manage/run them yourself - or let JPA run the scripts for you. But having it do so on start up or deployment in production is a bad idea - restarting a production server after an outage should not have it issue DDL statements or check against the DB.

Comment: extendTables has a few holes that would require a lot of effort to fix for each database, beyond the scope of a developer convince method. This will work for many databases, but is intended for connections that can only see one set of tables. Quick fix is to log in as a user that can only see your one catalog in the DB. If going that route, create a different persistence unit just for the alter table functionality, and deploy/undeploy it with different connection settings/user for each catalog. Might be easier to control using the SchemaManager functionality directly though

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Chris! But the method you proposed seems not to work for me. I reduced access rights of my user to only one schema but the function "extendTables" that I quoted still finds all the column definitions from other schemas. I guess the access rights don't affect the possibility to just view the table definitions.

Comment: This works for other JDBC drivers, so you might check MySQL's JDBC drivers forums, bugs and docs to see if they have a solution for it. Another alternative might be to modify the extendTables method to find a way to filter ColumnInfo that works on MySQL. EclipseLink is open source, so can be rebuilt/repackages with your modified class.  I'm sure others (like myself) would appreciate if you contributed it if you got something working, though EclipseLink official fix would need to build such behaviour into the DatabasePlatform and MySQLPlatform classes so it doesn't affect other databases.